# using AlarmManager.setRepeating to run a service every 5 seconds

Tags: android, alarmmanager

After scourging stackoverflow and the web I am still frustrated and running into issues. I am attempting to make a service that will poll sensors periodically and send that data somewhere. I have started at the ground level, just trying to get the service to display a toast every x seconds so I know that it is indeed working.

I started by making an alarm receiver, where I initialized the service intent that I want to run periodically. That code can be found below.

```
package com.example.cnash.raf;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
         Context oAppContext = context.getApplicationContext();

         if (oAppContext == null) {
             oAppContext = context;
         }

         Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(oAppContext, MyService.class);
         oAppContext.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

After that, I quickly made my service and just put a toast in the onStartCommand, just to test to see if the service was being started every x seconds.

```
package com.example.cnash.raf;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

After that, I made a setupAlarm method in my main activity and followed some steps to set that up. I use an Alarm Manager to do a .setRepeating, and then after that I finish the activity. But by my understanding the alarm should still be set to repeat every x seconds.

```
package com.example.cnash.raf;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupAlarm(5);
    }

    private void setupAlarm(int seconds) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmManager.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                MainActivity.this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();
        t.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        int interval = seconds*1000;
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, t.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

When I run this app, I can see a white screen quickly come up and disappear. This I am certain is the activity_main booting up on onCreate and then disappearing when I call finish(); But after the activity_main pops up and disappears, nothing happens. I am expecting to see a Toast pop up every 5000 ms, but it doesn't.

Also, I am going to include my AndroidManifest file because I am still iffy on whether or not I set that up right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cnash.raf">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Small side question not related: a quick think-ahead, I was going to put my sensor polling data into MyService, where I would use SensorManagers and what-not. Is this the right place to put something of that sort, or does it belong in another class that I would call through MyService via Intent?

Comment: If I'm right, you won't be able to set repeating interval lower then 60 seconds. If you try to set lower, then it will ignore and set to 60 sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that I noticed here is:

1.Name of your broadcast receiver is `AlarmReceiver`. But in code you are using `AlarmManager.class`

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), **AlarmManager.class**);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            MainActivity.this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), **AlarmReceiver.class**);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            MainActivity.this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

2. I cannot find the declaration of your broadcast Receiver (`AlarmReceiver`) in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Fix these two and it should work. Enjoy :)

Comment: Wow still can't believe how stupid I am calling the wrong class. 
Anyway, adding the declaration of my receiver to the manifest worked! Thanks again!